# visual studio 2015 <vector>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 after using 2013 for a few years. My C++ application throws an error on

```
#include <vector>
```

and other similar statements. None of these standard libraries seem to be available. Is there something else I must install? I tried installing the MFC add-on and it threw some bad looking errors.

Comment: The include statement got edited. I was just trying to say I could not include the vector library.

Comment: Your installation is terribly broken.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a collection of STDLib when you create a new C++ template with VS2015, used that instead.

Comment: please provide error message you got

Comment: *"My C++ application throws an error "* - Please post the exact error you get. Without any more information, you cannot hope to get help. Although this really looks like a badly broken installation.

Comment: Post the error you got please.

Comment: `stdafx.h` huh?